# How can I call <DocumentReference>.listCollections() in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get all the collections that exist inside a given document after a Firestore delete trigger.

When deploying my function, I get an error log saying:

> TypeError: change.ref.listCollections is not a function

Same thing happens if I try to get the reference from `admin.firestore()`:

> TypeError: admin.firestore(...).doc(...).listCollections is not a function

I would expect for this function to actually work, as its code is still defined here:
[**source**](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/master/dev/src/reference.ts#L263).

I tried to call this function in the simplest way possible:
`admin.firestore().listCollections()`

```
export const myFunction = functions.firestore.document(...).onDelete(async (snap, context) => {
  const subcollections = await snap.ref.listCollections()
  console.log(`Retrieved ${subcollections.lenght} subcollections.`)
  return null
})
```

The only reason that I can think of could be that the reference points to a deleted document, and it can't be used to list subcollections. But, should that be the case, `admin.firestore().listCollections()` should not fail.

Comment: What version of firebase-functions are you using?

Comment: From my `package.json`: firebase-admin: "^6.4.0", firebase-functions: "^2.1.0".

Comment: What version of @google-cloud/firestore are you ending up with?  Run `npm list` to dump the dependencies.

Comment: `npm list` shows: @google-cloud/firestore@0.19.0 - I can post the rest if it's needed.

Comment: I'm just not able to reproduce a problem here.  It's working fine for me.  listCollections was added in 0.17 so unless you managed to get an old version of @google-cloud/firestore, I don't know what's going on.

Comment: I tried to completely uninstall node/npm, deleted the project, reinstalled everything and redeployed. It works now, but I don't know why.